# Execute .jar from Python

Tags: java, python, os.system

I am trying to build a very simple python script to automate minifying/combining some css/js assets.

I am not sure how to properly handle the minification step. I use yui-compressor and usually call the jar directly from the command line.

Assuming the build script is in the same directory as rhino `js.jar` and `yui-compressor.jar`, I'd be able to compress a css/js file like so:

```
java -cp js.jar -jar yuicompressor-2.4.4.jar -o css/foo.min.css css/foo.css
```

Calling that from the terminal works fine, but in the python build file, it does not
eg, `os.system("...")`
The exit status being returned is `0`, and no output is being returned from the command (for example, when using `os.popen()` instead of `os.system()`)

I'm guessing it has something to do with paths, perhaps with java not resolving properly when calling to `os.system()`… any ideas?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Include your Python code in the question.

Comment: It is that exact command above called using os.system:
`os.system("java -cp js.jar -jar yuicompressor-2.4.4.jar -o css/foo.min.css css/foo.css")`
the script and jars all live in the same directory and are called from that directory

Answer (score 3):

I have a somewhat similar case, when I want a python program to build up some commands and then run them, with the output going to the user who fired off the script. The code I use is:

```
import subprocess
def run(cmd):
   call = ["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]
   ret = subprocess.call(call, stdout=None, stderr=None)
   if ret > 0:
      print "Warning - result was %d" % ret

run("javac foo.java")
run("javac bar.java")
```

In my case, I want all commands to run error or not, which is why I don't have an exception raised on error. Also, I want any messages printed straight to the terminal, so I have stdout and stderr be None which causes them to not go to my python program. If your needs are slightly different for errors and messages, take a look at the http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html documentation for how to tweak what happens.

(I ask bash to run my command for me, so that I get my usual path, quoting etc)

Answer (score 0):

os.system should return 0 when the command executes correctly. 0 is the standard return code for success.

Does it print output when run from the command line?

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this in Python? For tasks like this, especially Java, you are better off using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). Write commands in xml and then ant runs for you.

Comment: I think the point is that you've got some existing code in Java that you need to integrate with a Python script you happen to be writing. In general, you could write anything in Java in Python, but that doesn't make it practical.